# extract data using regular expression between three fixed characters

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

This is the data string i am using.

```
f = """{"id"=156,"pid"=656,"sd"=656,"id"=156,"pid"=656}"""
```

I want to read value of id. so I am using

```
regex = '"id":(.+?),"pid"'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
ida = re.findall(pattern,f)
```

now regex returns two values of id.
I want to read only id value between "id" and "sd". how can we write a regex statement to include "pid" and "sd"  to get only value of first "id"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.findall()` returns all the matches for a pattern instead you can use `re.search` to get the value of first`id` :

```
>>> re.search(r'"id"=(\d+)',f).group(1)
'156'
```

Note that if you just want to find the first occurrence of a pattern you don't need another extra conditions, `re.search` will return that by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookarounds regex:

```
>>> f = """{"id"=156,"pid"=656,"sd"=656,"id"=156,"pid"=656}"""
>>> print re.search(r'(?<="id"=)(\w+)(?=.*"sd")', f).group()
156
```

`(?=.*"sd")` will make sure `"sd"` is after our match.

`(?<="id"=)` will make sure that `"id"=` is just before our match.